# Use if in where statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

I have 4 table:

1. Table_op_type
2. Table_maintenancetype
3. Table_repair_time
4. Table_repair_type

Each table has one column that can true or false and I have one `Table_maintenancereport` that has many columns and 4 columns in `Table_maintenancereport` foreign key given from 4 up table when I select `Table_maintenancereport` and one row in each table is true code working fine but when more than one row returned from table give this error.

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

How can I fix it?

My code is:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table_maintenancereport
WHERE mtypeid IN (IIF(@smtype = 1, (SELECT Table_maintenancetype.id FROM Table_maintenancetype WHERE enable_search = 1), mtypeid))
  AND op_typeid IN (IIF(@sop IN (1), (SELECT Table_op_type.id FROM Table_op_type WHERE enable_search = 1), op_typeid))
  AND repaire_timeid IN (IIF(@stime IN (1), (SELECT Table_repair_time.id FROM Table_repair_time WHERE enable_search = 1), repaire_timeid))
  AND repaire_typeid IN (IIF(@stype = 1, (SELECT Table_repair_type.id FROM Table_repair_type WHERE enable_search = 1), repaire_typeid));
```

Comment: write your whole code sample, it is not clear with this input only.

Comment: `mtypeid IN ( iif(@smtype=1,(select Table_maintenancetype.id from Table_maintenancetype where enable_search=1),mtypeid))` this thing does not make sense at all, what is your intention here?

Comment: The problem isn't the `IIF` it's your subqueries; the error is telling you exactly what the problem is. This, however, seems like you would be better off with some proper `JOIN` syntax and proper boolean logic.

Comment: Your each sub query is returning more than one value i.e other 3 tables are returning more than one value, try using `distinct`. Rewrite statement with case expression instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fix the `where` conditions.  You can do this with basic logic operators.  Sets cannot be returned by `iif()` or by `case()` expressions.

So:

```
WHERE (@smtype <> 1 OR
       mtypeid IN (SELECT Table_maintenancetype.id FROM Table_maintenancetype WHERE enable_search = 1)
      ) AND
      (@sop <> 1 OR
       op_typeid IN (SELECT Table_op_type.id FROM Table_op_type WHERE enable_search = 1)
      ) AND
      (@stime <> 1 OR
       repaire_timeid IN (SELECT Table_repair_time.id FROM Table_repair_time WHERE enable_search = 1)
      ) AND
      (@stype <> 1 OR
       repaire_typeid IN (SELECT Table_repair_type.id FROM Table_repair_type WHERE enable_search = 1)
      );
```

Answer (score 1):

If I am interpreting what you are trying to do correctly:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table_maintenancereport mr
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table_maintenancetype mt ON mr.mtypeid = mt.id AND enable_search = 1
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table_op_type ot ON mr.op_typeid = ot.id AND enable_search = 1
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table_repair_time rt ON mr.repaire_timeid = rt.id AND enable_search = 1
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table_repair_type rty ON mr.repaire_typeid = rty.id AND enable_search = 1
WHERE (ISNULL(@smtype,-1) != 1 OR mt.id IS NOT NULL)
AND (ISNULL(@sop,-1) != 1 OR ot.id IS NOT NULL)
AND (ISNULL(@stime,-1) != 1 OR rt.id IS NOT NULL)
AND (ISNULL(@stype,-1) != 1 OR rty.id IS NOT NULL)
```

so for each @variable, if it is set to 1, the corresponding field has to be one of the search enabled ids to appear in the output. If a variable is not set to 1, then it will not filter the corresponding field.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use `CASE WHEN` statement in where clause like:

```
   select
    *
from
    Table_maintenancereport
where
    case
        when @smtype = 1 then mtypeid in (
            select Table_maintenancetype.id
        from
            Table_maintenancetype
        where
            enable_search = 1)
        else mtypeid = mtypeid end

    ....
```

Comment: this code not worked iif and case has similar
but problem in returned value from subquery

Comment: @Mehrdad You could then use `top 1` for each sub query or `distinct`